# How to transpose rows into columns with powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, pivot, transpose

I have this input as an array name $discrepancies.

```
Source  Date    Store   Register Sales
XBR     8/1/2020    11741   517  1029.611
Xcenter 8/1/2020    11741   517  1047.701
XStore  8/1/2020    11741   517  1047.701
XBR     8/3/2020    11741   517  690.941
Xcenter 8/3/2020    11741   517  730.821
XStore  8/3/2020    11741   517  730.821
XBR     8/4/2020    11741   516  1027.311
Xcenter 8/4/2020    11741   516  1045.401
XStore  8/4/2020    11741   516  1045.401
XBR     8/7/2020    11741   516  688.641
Xcenter 8/7/2020    11741   516  728.521
XStore  8/7/2020    11741   516  728.521
```

I need to transpose the array to

```
Date        Store   Register    XBR         Xcenter     XStore
8/1/2020    11741   517         1029.611    1047.701    1047.701
8/3/2020    11741   517         90.941      730.821     730.821
8/4/2020    11741   516         027.311     1045.401    1045.401
8/7/2020    11741   516         688.641     728.521     728.521
```

I tried below codes but it works if the array has only one register.

```
> $discrepancies= import-csv -Path "$OuputFile\discrepancies.csv"
> 
> $pivot = @()
>     foreach ($Date in $discrepancies.Date | Select -Unique)     
>     {
>         $Props = [ordered]@{ Date = $Date }
>         foreach ($Store in $discrepancies.Store | Select -Unique) 
>         {
>             $Props += [ordered]@{ Store = $Store }
>             foreach ($Register in $discrepancies.Register | Select -Unique) 
>             {                
>                 $Props += [ordered]@{ Register = $Register }
>                 foreach ($Source in $discrepancies.Source | Select -Unique)
>                 { 
>                     $Sales = ($discrepancies.where({ $_.Source -eq $Source -and 
>                                 $_.Date -eq $Date -and $_.Store -eq $Store -and $_.Register -eq $Register})).Sales
>                     $Props += @{ $Source = $Sales }
>                 } 
>             }
>         }
>         $pivot += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Props
>     }
```

I received several "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary:" error message if there are multiple registers in the array. I guess error related to inserting duplicate keys into dictionary but I don't know how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there always only one record per _source_ per day? Or do you need to be able to handle if there's multiple entries for `XBR` on the same register in the same store on the same date for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and break down the problem into two discrete steps:

1. Group discrepancies based on Date, Store and Register
2. Output an object describing the Date, Store, Register and all sources associated with that group

For the first step, we can make use of `Group-Object`:

```
$discrepancies |Group Store,Register,Date
```

Now that we've grouped the input correctly, we can move ahead with constructing our output:

```
$discrepancies |Group Store,Register,Date |ForEach-Object {
    $entries = $_.Group
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date     = $entries[0].Date
        Store    = $entries[0].Store
        Register = $entries[0].Register
        XBR      = ($entries |Where-Object Source -eq XBR).Sales
        XCenter  = ($entries |Where-Object Source -eq XCenter).Sales
        XStore   = ($entries |Where-Object Source -eq XStore).Sales
    }
}
```

All entries in each group necessarily has the same Date, Store and Register value (because that's what we asked `Group-Object` to group on), so for those we just copy the value of the first entry in the group.

Comment: It's completely a different approach and works fantastic! When I exported the transposed array to CSV, there is time stamp (e.g. 9/4/2020 12:00:00 AM) after the date. How can I get rid of the time stamp and sort the date field? Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mixer If the `Date` property on the input is a `[datetime]` value you can do `Date     = $entries[0].Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy")` to fix that

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have to cast date to [datetime] and it works now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Mathias beat me to it, I feel obligated to post it since I did the work. Very similar to his approach but his is probably faster on larger data sets. Also, please try to provide actual CSV sample in the future.

```
$csvdata = @'
Source  Date    Store   Register Sales
XBR     8/1/2020    11741   517  1029.611
Xcenter 8/1/2020    11741   517  1047.701
XStore  8/1/2020    11741   517  1047.701
XBR     8/3/2020    11741   517  690.941
Xcenter 8/3/2020    11741   517  730.821
XStore  8/3/2020    11741   517  730.821
XBR     8/4/2020    11741   516  1027.311
Xcenter 8/4/2020    11741   516  1045.401
XStore  8/4/2020    11741   516  1045.401
XBR     8/7/2020    11741   516  688.641
Xcenter 8/7/2020    11741   516  728.521
XStore  8/7/2020    11741   516  728.521
'@ -split "`n" -replace '\s+',',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csvdata | Group-Object -Property date -AsHashTable | foreach {
    foreach($date in $_.keys)
    {
        $_.$date | Group-Object -Property source -AsHashTable |foreach {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Date     = $date
                Store    = $_.values.store | select -first 1
                Register = $_.values.register | select -first 1
                XBR      = $_['XBR'].sales
                XCenter  = $_['XCenter'].sales
                XStore   = $_['XStore'].sales
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely will include actual CSV next time. Thank you for your help Doug.